# How to access the mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am using python MySQL 5.7.19 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 and I am
trying to run the following code

```
import MySQLdb
db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root",YES,"testDB")
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USER")
sql="""CREATE TABLE USER(
       ID  INT(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       USERNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
       PASSWORD VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (ID)
       )"""
cursor.execute(sql)
db.close()
```

---

When I save this in a `.py` file and execute it as Python3 I get the following error:

> $ python3 try.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "try.py", line 1, in 
>     import MySQLdb
>
> ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

---

[image: here's the screenshot:]

---

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you install that package?

Comment: pip install PyMySQL

Answer (score 0):

install the package

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

or on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the package using this command

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

and then use these thing to avoid non ascii character issue and persistent mysql db connection issue.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "db_pswd", "mysql_db", charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
db.ping(True)
```

use `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb` don't specify python version, when system try to install, it will find the current python version in this system.